# Swap one TypeScript type with another inside an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following types:

```
type Target = number | undefined;

type MyObject = {
    some: string;
    properties: string;
    id: Target;
}
```

I want to come up with a generic way to replace `Target` with `number`, like:

```
type MyObjectTransformed = TargetToNumber<MyObject>;

/**
 * MyObjectTransformed is now:
 * 
 * {
 *     some: string;
 *     properties: string;
 *     id: number;
 * }
 */
```

It's easy if you know `Target` is always in the `id` field, I don't need help with that.

But what if `Target` could be anywhere? Like this should also work:

```
TargetToNumber<{
    some: string;
    other: Target;
    properties: string;
}>
```

And even worse... it also needs to work when it's nested! Like this should still replace `Target` with `number`:

```
TargetToNumber<{
    some: string;
    properties: string;
    nested: {
        arbitrarily: {
            deep: Target;
        };
    };
}>
```

If you're curious why I want to do such a strange thing, [this is why I'm asking](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb/pull/151#issuecomment-576197004).

Comment: Look into conditional types https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/

Comment: Can you not just make `Target` generic in the first place? i.e. `type MyObject<T> = { ..., id: T }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a conditional type: if the arbitrary type `T` is `A` or a subtype of `A`, we replace it with `B`, otherwise if it's an object type we map the properties recursively, otherwise we leave the type as `T`.

```js
type TargetToNumber<T> = SubstituteType<T, Target, number>;

type SubstituteType<T, A, B> =
    T extends A
    ? B
    : T extends {}
    ? { [K in keyof T]: SubstituteType<T[K], A, B> }
    : T;
```

If you only want to substitute exactly `A` and leave subtypes of `A` alone (e.g. `never` is always a subtype...) you can replace `T extends A` with `[A, T] extends [T, A]` to test that they are the same type.

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgJwOYWFAvFAdgVwLYBGECUAPlDlgCYQBmAllhFQNwBQboksiKwMAewBy+IggA8MAHwYoAZRwEAzsHrAcwCDHARJAGh7JUB3IWJSOXaAuWr1m7ZH1QAggYBCM9Gyi-YUCAAPTWolVx8-AH4odwjfAC5-IJCqMIBvAF84qGi0qABtAGkoRigAawgQAVpYAF1EmxU1DS0dSSLagzcYmSy-KESYDksdWAgVAEZZeCN+YVFicTTspQE8CESVBEYkdn6wBAFIBFVxzeBtrF3s+ipB3lR2DKl2TlGYceAAJmmHuZEzBJlv1Vutzpdrv0BMAABbEe6zPZ+A5HYinJTgnZPF4jbgfFQAZl+s0EALESxWaw2UC2WOyKOO6MxVyRviYKmYiWB-T8iAIagQiHoABsQFzsjy-DQIGAEXxWTyMgqlWxnkA)

Comment: Maybe I should make another question, but I have a followup if you have another minute:

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#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-AAdMC-kA

Comment: The `some` property can be protected by the `[A, T] extends [T, A]` trick. The `properties` property cannot be, since its type is `number | undefined` which is the same as your `Target`. Typescript has a structural type system, not a nominal type system, so there is no way to distinguish between two structurally equal types with different names; one workaround is to define `type Target = (number | undefined) & { __brand: 'Target' }` so that it's structurally different from `number | undefined`, and use type assertions like `23 as Target` to convert from `number` to `Target`.